# Cannot load csb file in Cocos2d-x 3.3rc0 and cocos studio 2.0.5?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to run some samples Cocos2d-x provided. And I followed the tutorial and I am OK with Cocos Studio part. But after I publish my resource and create a visual studio project. I met this error. When I debug, I always get `rootNode` 0x00000000 .

```
auto rootNode = CSLoader::createNode("MainScene.csb");
```

I am sure I have publish Cocos Studio project successfully, cause I get "MainScene.csb" and other resources under "/res" folder.

I am using Cocos2d-x 33rc0 and Cocos Studio 2.0.5 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: When your app crashes (or breakpoint hit), attach a debugger, walk call stack top to bottom, watch variables and you will find an error quickly (either on your side or on side of cocos guys). You should also prefer release versions: cocos2d-x 3.3 was released a week ago or so (and there was also rc1 before it), along with Cocos Studio 2.0.6. Most probably, you make cocos to search a file in a folder that you did not add to the search list, or misspelled it's filename or folder name or something like this.

Answer (score -1):

You must use cocos2d-x 3.3 final